# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Label

Tags: python, tkinter

Пробую сделать первую диалоговую программу

При нажатии запускаю второй скрипт, который создает список файлов по вписанному пути. 2 остальных поля на будущее, пока пытаюсь реализовать хотя бы одно.

main:

```
from tkinter import *
   

def click_button():
    os.system('main1.py')


root = Tk()
root.title("Проверка файлов")

build = StringVar()
instalbuild = StringVar()
tempbuild = StringVar()

build = Label(text="Путь к папке со сборкой:")
instalbuild = Label(text="Путь к установленной программе:")
tempbuild = Label(text="Путь к папке \Local\Temp\сборка:")

build.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
instalbuild.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
tempbuild.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")

build_entry = Entry(textvariable=build)
instalbuild_entry = Entry(textvariable=instalbuild)
tempbuild_entry = Entry(textvariable=tempbuild)

build_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
instalbuild_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
tempbuild_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

btn = Button(text="Проверить", command = click_button)

btn.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

main1:

```
import os, csv
from main import instalbuild

path = instalbuild
filelist = []
with open("files.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
      for file in files:
        filelist.append(os.path.join(file))
    for name in filelist:
       # print(name)
        print(name,  file=f)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему

UP

Сократил, переменная сохраняется:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
master = Tk()


def return_entry(en):
    global content
    content = entry.get()
    os.system('main1.py')


Label(master, text="Путь: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
entry = Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)


entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry)


mainloop()
```

Но при попытке передать переменную встретил ошибку

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main1.py", line 2, in
>
> from main import content ImportError: cannot import name 'content' from 'main'
> (C:\Users\korolyov_m\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py)

Comment: `build = StringVar()` `build = Label(text="Путь к папке со сборкой:")` `build_entry = Entry(textvariable=build)` - вот тут вы что делаете? Вы создали переменную, потом перезаписали ее другим значением, потом пытаетесь build как будто это все StringVar передать в Entry. Нельзя использовать одно и то же имя для разных вещей, и думать, что при этом все нормально будет работать.

Comment: Собственно, в instalbuild у вас записан объект Label, и вы этот объект пытаетесь использовать как путь к файлу, на этом моменте и вылетает ошибка.